# When does $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x^p \log^q x} dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

What are the values of $p$, $q$ for which an improper below is convergent?:

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x^p \log^q x}dx$$

I divided the case and did a comparison test, substitution. But I want an easier way.

Do you have some idea?

Comment: Use Cauchy Condensation Test, in conjunction with Integral test.

Comment: Asymptotically, $\log^a x$ is $O(x^p)$ for any $p>0$. Thus, for $p<1$, you can compare the integral to that of $\frac{1}{x^p}$ and show it diverges. Similarly for $p>1$, you can compare to the integral $1/{x^{p+\epsilon}}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and see it converges. The case for $p=1$ should be done by u-substitution.